# Why the sum of variances

Tags: variance

[image]

I have this dataset and I am being asked why the total variance is not equal to the sum of each segments. I believe it has something to do with dependent and independent datasets. How would I calculate the variance if they are dependent?

Edit 1:
They are sales figures for a company. I calculated the variance over previous year for each category as well as the total overall sales. So really it is the growth from the previous year more than variance. When you calculate the sum of each category you do not get the same as the growth for the total.

Edit 2:
I can't comment on responses but yes that is correct. "So the question is why the relative difference for the total is not the same as the sum of relative differences for the seperate segments. – Sextus Empiricus" Is exactly what I am trying to figure out.

Edit 3: is there a way to get the sum of each segment to equal the total?

Comment: Could you explain to us in greater detail what is your data, what does the table show, and what are you trying to do? Obviously, the negative values are not variances.

Comment: The variance here is defined as the difference between the years 2021 and 2020. (Not the [variance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) that is usual in statistics). So the question is why the relative difference for the total is not the same as the sum of relative differences for the seperate segments.

Comment: what is the sample size for the several Segments?

Comment: You can answer this question yourself by simplifying it.  For instance, let there be two segments, Segment 1 grows from 98 to 99 year to year (essentially a 1% increase) while Segment 2 shrinks from 2 to 1 during the same period (a 50% decrease).  The total change across both segments is zero.  Construct the table and think about it.